# Resize image in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to load and resize an image to 416x416. However I still get the same image size.

Code:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function readURL(input) {
    if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {;
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = e.target.result
            image.addEventListener("load",function(){
             ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 416,416)
            })
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

I have read lot of post about this but everything indicates that the code should be correct, where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: And you never set your canvas size? Can you provide a **complete** example. (Also, you don't need the FileReader, ise a blobURI instead)

Answer (score 1):

You might get such a situation in case if you not set the canvas size.

Resize is not working if canvas size wasn't set:

```js
const width = 416;
const height = 416;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
//canvas.width = width;
//canvas.height = height;

function readURL(input) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {;
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result
      image.addEventListener("load", function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height)
      })
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" />
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Resize is working if canvas size was set:

```js
const width = 416;
const height = 416;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function readURL(input) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {;
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result
      image.addEventListener("load", function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height)
      })
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" />
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what is OP's problem, but if you did read the link you provided, you would have seen that your code block should do exactly the same thing as OP's one. The 5 args version defaults the sx sy sw and sh arguments to 0,0,sourceMedia.width,sourceMedia.height (i.e naturalWidth/naturalHeight for an image). Hence your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I hurried with the answer and was wrong. Thanks for a notice.